# RSS feeds on the homepage have the wrong label and link

Tags: bug, feed

The RSS feeds (under the HNQ list) on each site's homepage somehow have the wrong label and link:

- On [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

  - Bugs → Monthly
  - Reqs → (missing)
  - Active → Recent
  - Bountied → Bountied (correct)
  - Hot → Bountied
  - Week → Hot
  - Month → Weekly
- On [all SE sites](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/)*

  - Active → Recent
  - Hot → Bountied
  - Week → Hot
  - Month → Weekly
- On [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/)

  - Apps → (missing, probably by design)
  - Scripts → (missing, probably by design)
  - Active → Recent
  - Hot → Bountied
  - Week → Hot
  - Month → Weekly

Example:

> [image: Weekly questions on Meta Stack Exchange...]
>
> [image: ...links to the Hot questions feed]

---

<sup>*Not sure about Stack Overflow since Teams member is only shown "Recently Active" questions and RSS feed</sup>